# Java Servlet mapping when using a filter

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am quite new to using Servlets and JSP but I was wondering if someone can help me with the following question I have.

My problem arises from the fact that my Servlet is not being invoked, and I can't seem to figure out why.

Currently my steup is that I have a filter class named VisitShopFilter which checks to see if a client is logged in before they visit the shop, if they are it just forwards the request to the shop.jsp page,if they are not then it forwards them to the login.jsp page.

Here is the VisitShopFilter:

```
   @Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpSession sess = ((HttpServletRequest)servletRequest).getSession();
    if(sess.getAttribute("loggedIn") == null){
            servletRequest.getRequestDispatcher("login.jsp").forward(servletRequest,servletResponse);
            return;
        }
    if(sess.getAttribute("cart") == null){
        sess.setAttribute("cart",new ShoppingCart());
    }
    servletRequest.getRequestDispatcher("shop.jsp").forward(servletRequest,servletResponse);
}
```

The filter is mapped the the URL pattern /Shop

On the shop.jsp Page I have the following form :`<form onaction="Shop" method = "POST">
                <input type = "hidden" name = "itemname" value = "testItem"/>
                <input type = "hidden" name = "itemprice" value = "10.00"/>
                <input type = "hidden" name = "itemquantity" value = "1"/>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-submit">Add to cart</button>
                </form>`

and I also have a Servlet named "Shop":

```
    @Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    System.out.println("responding to post");
    if(req.getSession().getAttribute("cart") == null || req.getSession().getAttribute("loggedIn") == null){
        req.getRequestDispatcher("login.jsp").forward(req,resp);
    }

    ShoppingCart cart = (ShoppingCart) req.getSession().getAttribute("cart");
    try{
        cart.addItem(
                req.getParameter("itemname"),
                Double.valueOf(req.getParameter("itemprice")),
                Integer.valueOf(req.getParameter("itemquantity"))
        );
    }catch (NumberFormatException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    req.getSession().setAttribute("itemNamesInCart",cart.getItemNames());
    req.getSession().setAttribute("itemPricesInCart",cart.getItemPrices());
    req.getSession().setAttribute("itemQuantitiesInCart",cart.getItemQuantities());
    req.getSession().setAttribute("totalItemsInCart",cart.getTotalCartSize());
    req.getSession().setAttribute("totalPurchasePrice",cart.getTotal());

    req.getRequestDispatcher("shop.jsp").forward(req, resp);
}
```

My problem is, "responding to post" isn't even printed out when clicking the submit button for the form. In my web.xml file I have tried mapping the servlet to /Shop, /shop.jsp and a bunch of other things including switching between GET and POST methods and I just can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Please post your web.xml too.

Comment: What is the URL path for that POST request? Try setting it on the form (maybe you wanted to do that with `onaction='Shop'`, should be `action='Shop'`).

Comment: You should have the line chain.doFilter(request, response);   somewhere in your doFilter method.

Answer (score 0):

> Currently my steup is that I have a filter class named VisitShopFilter which checks to see if a client is logged in before they visit the shop, if they are it just forwards the request to the shop.jsp page,if they are not then it forwards them to the login.jsp page.

Bad idea.

A filter should be an interceptor that provides common functionality for a set of resources (like how you check for session). You should have actual resources (Servlets/jsps) mapped to your end points. When a filter is done with it's work, it should invoke chain.doFilter(...) which lets the request processing reach its mapped end point.

A filter should change the course of request processing (by invoking another resource) only on exceptions (logical, business or technical). And as you have it in your code already, it does that by invoking the request dispatcher.

Comment: Really? An authentication filter that checks for sessions is quite a common pattern.

Comment: You are right. But where in my post have I suggested otherwise ?

Comment: Maybe I misread. Seems the "Bad Idea" only refers to the part where the forward is done even in the non-error case (when there already is a session). I agree that it is better (and probably solves the problem at hand of the Servlet not being reached) to just let request processing resume (and not forward anywhere explicitly).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everybody for your fast replies.

I have taken into account what each one of you have said and managed to Improve from there. The two problems ended up being that I accidentally had onaction in the HTML file instead of action, and that I wasn't calling chain.doFilter(req,resp) method.